# PHP: Find all subdirectories in a directory. If they have a valid XML file, work with it

Tags: php, recursion, directory, subdirectory

I need to get all available subdirectories in a directory, save that directory's name, and if they include an XML file, work with that file.

Here is a bit of code and some comments I wrote.

```
   <?php 
   $path = "http://source.com/path/to/subs/";
   //Check for any subdirectories
         foreach($subdirectory as $sub){
              $name = //subdirectory's name;
              // Filepath is always http://source.com/path/to/subs/name_of_sub/description.xml
              $file = $path . $name . 'description.xml'; 
              if(file_exists($file)){
                    //do my stuff here
              }
        }
  //end check
  ?>
```

Comment: many PHP functions: opendir, readdir, glob, scandir ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are referring to an HTTP URI, not a directory in your question.
Unfortunately, there are no dirs or files in HTTP URIs.
So, you cannot find any subdirs this way.

If you are limited to HTTP URI, there is no solution.
However, if it's your own server which filesystem you have access to, nothing could be easier - just open local directory with your code, instead of an HTTP URI

Comment: Yeah, this is a third-party's system. I wanted to grab all the XML files that exist there and import them for preview.

Comment: @dodododo So, do you have FTP or SSH access? Or is there some kind of index available with the **URLs** to the XML files? Otherwise: not possible. A URL *might* map to a similar file path on the server's file system, but that's totally arbitrary and as the client, you cannot know it.